# Undefined index from a drop down box using jQuery

Tags: php, html

I cannot seem to get the value from my dropdown box which is using JQuery linked up to my database, into an SQL statement?
Where is the error?

Thanks

Here is my PHP:

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <p class="timetable-p">Room code:
            <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
                <form action="" method="post"><?php
                    echo '<option class="option">Type/Select a room</option>';
                    while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
                        $code = $row['roomcode'];
                        $titles[] = $row['park'];
                        echo '<option class="option" name="codedrop">'.$code.'</option>';
                    }
                        ?>
                        <input type="submit" value="subm" name="subm">
                        </form>
                        <?php
                        if( isset( $_POST['subm'] ) )
                        {

                    $codedropOption= $_POST['codedrop'];

                        $resql = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMS' WHERE 'roomCode' LIKE '$codedrop%'";
                        $res1 = mysql_query($resql);

            echo "<table>";             
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1)){                         
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td>";
            }
            echo "</table>"; 
                    }


                ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using two forms?

Comment: Why are you using a `form` tag inside a `select` tag ?

Comment: Nested Forms Are Not Allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** Remove `name="codedrop"` from `<option>` Like

```
echo '<option class="option">'.$code.'</option>';
```

**N.B.:** Only `<select>` bears the name attribute, not `<option>`.

**2)** Remove first `<form>`, it's of no use. And even, nested `<form>` are not allowed.

**3)** Change

```
$codedropOption= $_POST['codedrop'];
```

To

```
$codedropOption= $_POST['combobox'];
```

to not get

> Undefined index: codedrop

**4)** Change

```
$resql = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMS' WHERE 'roomCode' LIKE '$codedrop%'";
```

To

```
$resql = "SELECT * FROM ROOMS WHERE roomCode LIKE '$codedrop%'";
```

Use `backtick` in place of `single quotes` `'`.

**5)** Change

```
$resql = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMS' WHERE 'roomCode' LIKE '$codedrop%'";
```

To

```
$resql = "SELECT * FROM ROOMS WHERE roomCode LIKE '$codedropOption%'";
```

**Updated Code**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p class="timetable-p">Room code:
    <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
        <?php
      echo '<option class="option">Type/Select a room</option>';
      while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
          $code = $row['roomcode'];
          $titles[] = $row['park'];
          echo '<option class="option">'.$code.'</option>';
      }?>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" value="subm" name="subm">
</form>

<?php
if( isset( $_POST['subm'] ) )
{
    $codedropOption= $_POST['combobox'];

    $resql = "SELECT * FROM ROOMS WHERE roomCode LIKE '$codedropOption%'";
    $res1 = mysql_query($resql);

    echo "<table>";             
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1)){                         
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['roomCode'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Style'] . "</td><td>" . $row['dataProjector'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Whiteboard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['OHP'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['wheelchairAccess'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['lectureCapture'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radioSelect' value= '". $row['roomCode']."'></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I also forgot to change my SQL query to '$codedropOption%' but it still comes up with 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,'

Comment: show me your `$resql` code here in comment section @James

Comment: Have you gone through all my 5 steps @James ??

Comment: if( isset( $_POST['subm'] ) )
      {
       $codedropOption= $_POST['combobox'];

       $resql = "SELECT * FROM 'ROOMS' WHERE roomCode LIKE '$codedropOption%'";
       $res1 = mysql_query($resql) or die($resq1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
      //if ($res1 == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $res1<br />");
      echo "<table>";

Comment: Use this `$resql = "SELECT * FROM ROOMS WHERE roomCode LIKE '$codedropOption%'";` See my 4th and 5th point carefully @James